# Executing a stored procedure on every row in a SQL Server Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, cursor

So I've spent quite some time around Stack Overflow looking to make this bit of SQL that will populate a field in a view the amount of work days a project has been late.

The view joins data from two local tables on MS SQL Server (2008), and I've already written the stored procedure to calculate the work days in between two days, called by:

```
EXECUTE spWorkDaysLate '01/01/20XX', '01/02/20XX'
```

However I am not sure how to loop through each record in the view, as this needs to be done for every entry in the table. Pertinent fields in my table are startDate, endDate, and I would populate the final field (daysLate) with the result from the stored procedure above, using endDate and startDate as parameters. I found some recommendations online for using the cursor command to loop through the table, this would be the SQL I would want to run:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @MyField int;
SET @MyField = 'daysLate' /* Do need to do this, or is the an argument I pass? */

BEGIN
    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    select top 1000 daysLate from dbo.vQualityControl


    OPEN @MyCursor 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @MyField

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      /*
         YOUR ALGORITHM GOES HERE   
      */

      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END; 

    CLOSE @MyCursor ;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;
```

I'm fairly new to SQL and so I know the pseudo code that I want to run is something like a for each loop, which in my mind I have looking like:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
      /* Bad code */
      daysLate.Value = EXECUTE spWorkDaysLate @startDate, @endDate;

      FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END;
```

I know thats syntactically wrong, so what should I place in the loop so that the field 'daysLate' gets populated with the result of the called stored procedure?

Comment: first of all what do you want to do but not looking at solutions first because most of the time not understanding the root problem will cause more issues

Comment: Execute my stored procedure so that the 'daysLate' field gets populated with the result. Every record in the table should have a unique result.

Comment: okay, so what's in the SP?

Comment: If you can, you should write your stored procedure as an in-line table valued function (if not, then a multi statement table valued function), and then you can use it for each row with [**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx).  - [When is a SQL function not a function? "If it’s not inline, it’s rubbish." - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2011/11/08/when-is-a-sql-function-not-a-function.aspx) - - [Inline Scalar Functions - Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions)

Comment: @SqlZim that is where i'm heading... it could be a simple as creating a scalar function to return the date and then update the desired table

Comment: I'll look in to what an in-line table valued function is. My thought was that with the 'spWorkDaysLate' stored procedure, I could just call it every time the cursor loops in the last sql statement, but I'll look into your suggestion - thanks!

Comment: Set based operations are the way to go in SQL. Doing something row by agonizing row is going to hurt and should be avoided when possible. [RBAR: ‘Row By Agonizing Row’](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar-row-by-agonizing-row/)

Comment: @TylerJones Start over. You haven't really defined what you want to accomplish. A view is not something that is populated or manipulated like a table. If you want to add a computed value to your view - and this value is only computed by executing a stored procedure - then you have reached a dead end. You can't do that. You will need to change your direction. What direction should you choose? That depends on what you are trying to accomplish. A view consists of nothing more than a single sql statement. You can't use a cursor, a loop, etc.

Comment: @SMor I see, after reading more about it I can see that I have been going in the wrong direction. Thank you guys for helping me see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you ever try FUNCTION, you can calculate the work days in between two days in your FUNCTION.

```
SELECT *, dbo.fn_WorkDaysLate (startDate, endDate) AS DaysLate FROM dbo.vQualityControl
--OR
UPDATE A
    SET A.DaysLate = dbo.fn_WorkDaysLate (A.startDate, A.endDate)
FROM dbo.vQualityControl A
```

Comment: I will look into using a function instead - thank you!